# Class disparition after using a classifier in SCP plugin for a classification

Tags: classification, image-classification, scp

I use a classifier in SCP plugin for a classification. I don't have any problem for load and the treatment works. However, my first class disappears for each test. For example, if my classifier contains 4 class, I can see all of class when classifier is load but in the final classification, the first class disappears. There are nothing in place of class1's polygons. I see the location of theoretical polygons from class 1 but these polygons are some holes in the shape layer.